# Django, post_delete, is it safe to use reverse relation?

Tags: django, django-signals

Suppose Album has Songs.

When songs are deleted, I 'd like to update the song count of album objects.
(Let's just assume that we store the count of songs in Database field)

Is it safe to do

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Song)
def set_song_count(sender, song, **kwargs):
  song.album_set.update_song_count()
```

Song has ForeignKey to Album. No M2M involved.

Comment: Uh, we're going to need a leetle more information about the relation(s) between these models. Is there, by any chance, a ManyToMany involved? In which case there are *non-atomic aspects* to the transaction. I've been bitten on the ass more than once by m2m.

Comment: @PeterRowell no M2m is involved.

Comment: OK, then the question is: after a delete, is 'song' still a valid object to do a song.album_set.foo() on? Dicey. The object probably still exists in memory, but the logic path the ORM uses to get to the album_set is unclear. I would create a test database with this simple case and then beat the crap out of it and see if things work the way you want them to. Good Luck. Ps. Watch out for timing windows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not safe. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-delete):

> Note that the object will no longer be in the database, so be very careful what you do with this instance.

The instance has gone from the database by this point. Trying to fetch `song.album_set` will (unless it has been prefetched elsewhere, which you cannot rely on) trigger a database query for objects related to this one. I don't think you will get an error, but because the object no longer exists in the database, you will simply get an empty result.

You could consider using the `pre_delete` signal to run some code that decrements the count for the associated albums. You could also do this in a `delete` method [on the model itself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete).